# How to skip the print dialogue box in Edge browser?

Tags: javascript

[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/I7Ubd.png ""

I want to skip this step while printing

Comment: Flagged as off-topic.

Comment: Im interested in this answer. There are probably some situations where unconfirmed printing is useful. Just thinking about annoying teachers || coworkers ;) ( if the printer randomly prints a few 1000 pages...)

Comment: Yeah, the code to do this would be considered hacking

Comment: If you want to do this for a single computer, you could maybe write an autohotkey script that recognizes the print receipt pattern and autoclicks on Print, but that's a workREALLYFARaround

Comment: Basically i am developing an POS system that will run on EDGE browser when i click the print button the receipt should print without any print preview dialogue prompt

Answer (score 0):

You can't. You can only request that print dialog is opened.  It's up to the user at that point to determine where they'd like the document to print.